# jQuery ajax unable retrieve json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

So here is the ajax call that is making the problem

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "src/login.php",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: {username: usr, password: pwd},
    success: function(json){
        loggedStatus=json.status;
        alert(json.status);
    }
});
```

It is succesfully passing the variables to the php file, but it isn't entering th success: part.
This is example of what the php file returns

```
{
    "status": "Wrong"
}
```

or

```
{
    "status": "154414707fe8d22bb6239648ce11a9c9bede1a3e"
}
```

Which is totaly fine.

Comment: Is there an error in the console when this runs (or anything at all helpful)?

Comment: console.log(json) in your success and see what it returns.

Comment: Nope nothing @Nathan Taylor

Comment: The console stays empyty @Koen

Comment: is the url you are using right?, also try putting the url as the first line after $.ajax({.

Comment: @user49029 How about the network tab of your inspector. Do you see the ajax call there?

Comment: @Nathan Yeah there is the ajax call

Comment: @Koen this seems to fix the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the url as the first parameter in your $.ajax({ function.

because the syntax is: `$.ajax(url[, options])`

Answer (score 2):

Also, try typing `json` instead of `JSON` in the dataType.
Avoid using `success`.
From the jQuery website :

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

A bit surprised to see this example on the jQuery ajax page :

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the dataType

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "src/login.php",
    data: {username: usr, password: pwd},
    success: function(result){
        var json = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
        alert(json.status);
    }
});
```